# @ symbol before var name in Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I'm not entirely sure how to Google this question, so I come here with an example. I'm looking at a selenium script that has an excerpt like the following:

```
def setup
  @starting_url = "https://www.example.com"
  @restricted_url = "https://www.example.com/restricted"
  @user_email = "foo@bar.com"
  @user_password = "notarealpassword"
  @headless_mode = false
  @page_timeout = 15 # seconds
  @log_file = 'log/development.log'
  @lineup_file = 'data/lineup1.csv'
  ... more code
end
```

My question is, why does every variable here get prefixed with an `@` symbol? This method is not part of a class. It is being written in the global scope. I understand the variables have significance in with an `@` symbol in the case of an explicit class, but what about here?

Comment: They're instance vars of the environment they're running in, here Selenium. Selenium scripts don't run in isolation: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/7-use-a-page-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those variables become instance variables in the scope of the `main` object. They will be available inside other methods also defined at the global scope. Local variables defined within methods at the global scope would go out of scope as soon as the method returned.

Illustration:

```
def foo
  lvar = 1
  @ivar = 2
end

def bar
  puts @ivar # will print 2 after foo() is called
  puts lvar  # will throw NameError
end

@ivar # => nil
foo   # initializes @ivar
@ivar # => 2
bar   # prints 2, throws NameError
lvar  # throws NameError
```

Comment: cool, I see. so the author is simply taking advantage of scoping it within the entire `main` object as a way of using a global variable across the rest of his script I guess.

Comment: Yes. These are definitely global vars in sheep's clothing.